# How to use wait() and notifyAll() to pause a function until a value is increased past a certain amount

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

I am having a small issue with a program I am writing, it is a bank simulator, and the specific part I am having issues with are with these two functions:

The following code is in the Account class:

```
    public synchronized boolean withdraw(int amount){
        try{
            System.out.println("Balance = " + balance + " amount = "+ amount);
            while(amount > balance){
                wait();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int currentBalance = balance;
        //Thread.yield(); // Try to force collision
        int newBalance = currentBalance - amount;
        balance = newBalance;
        return true;
    }
    public synchronized void deposit(int amount) {
        int currentBalance = balance;
        Thread.yield();   // Try to force collision
        int newBalance = currentBalance + amount;
        balance = newBalance;
        notifyAll();
    }
```

Edited to add the following:

The Bank class is what calls the withdraw and deposit functions: here is that code:

```
    public void transfer(int from, int to, int amount) {
        synchronized (this) {
            counter++;
            try {
                while (isTesting) {
                    wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (accounts[from].withdraw(amount)) {
                accounts[to].deposit(amount);
            }
       
            counter--;
            notifyAll();

            if (shouldTest()) test();
        }
    }
```

the wait() call in transfer() works perfectly and I don't think I should be concerned about its functionality. But as you can see the first call to withdraw checks to see if the transaction can happen, and if it can, it will return true and move on to deposit. When actually running the program, once in any thread the balance is below amount, the program freezes, it does not switch to another thread, I've confirmed this with print statements.

Basically what I need the withdraw function to do is to check the balance of the current account, and if the balance is lower than the amount to withdraw, it will wait for the available funds from other accounts to deposit.

I want deposit to be able to accept money from other threads and call the notifyAll() function to wake the thread currently waiting, and to check the condition again. Unfortunately, whenever the wait function is called, <strike>the program stops completely</strike> hangs, and all of the other threads are in the monitor state according to the debugger.

I really appreciate any help, and if there are any questions you have for me about my code, or if you want me to include more, feel free to ask me and I will edit the question. If there is another thread already asking the same question, would you mind helping me to find it? I searched online already and nothing I found helps with my specific situation. Thank you very much.

Comment: You code looks fine. The issue is likely in code that calls `withdraw` and `deposit`.

Comment: *"the program stops completely"* Then it would seem that you don't have any **other** threads that call `deposit()` while you are waiting for funds inside the `withdraw()` method. --- Of course, since we can't see any code that actually starts threads, we can only guess at that.

Comment: I've added more code, and I also fixed the phrasing with that sentence, I meant to say the program hangs, and doesn't stop completely.

Comment: Agree with Andreas. Also note if withdraw and deposit are running in the same thread and they are both synchronized, and you've called wait inside the synchronized block, not sure how deposit's yield will ever run to interrupt the wait. I think Andreas was suggesting you show the code that drives and orchestrates your threads.

Comment: Since the transfer() method is also synchronizing on this, it seems that only one transfer can be in progress at any time. Then, if the withdraw() function starts waiting for enough balance, it seemst that won't happen, because there isn't any other deposit coming in from the bank class (which is waiting for withdraw to succeed). Unless you have multiple Bank class instances, but we can't see that from the code you shared.